How to auto-rotate a rectangular image area by a few degrees so that its left border gets vertical (using command line tools like imagemagick)
I have several thousand images whose main characteristics are as in the attached picture: All images are in a (nearly) black frame, while the actual image content nearly always is on a white background.
Now I would like to rotate the actual image content so that this content's left border is vertical. Then I would like to crop (trim) the image so that the black border is thrown away, but keeping the actual content completely. That is, even if the area that holds the actual content is not perfectly rectangular, everything from that area must be kept, which means that small rests of the black frame could still be visible afterwards.
Given the number of images that I'd like to treat this way, I guess I'll have to do that using command line tools. In the past, I have used ImageMagick for that kind of jobs (for transformations that are a lot easier), but I really wouldn't mind combining several different tools to achieve the task.
What I have already tried:
I have researched how to deskew images, and this works most time. However, the deskewing methods I have found work by making text lines horizontal. This is nice because it makes reading easier, but of course in most cases the borders of the area that hold the text are not vertical or horizontal afterwards, respectively. That's not what I am after.
To explain in more, detail, I would like to:

Detect the left edge between the black frame and the area that holds the actual image content.
Fit a (invisible) straight line along that edge.
Determine the angle between that line and a vertical line.
Rotate the whole image by (the negative) of that angle so that the edge from step 1 becomes vertical.
Trim the image, throwing away as much of the black frame as possible, but thereby keeping the complete area that holds the actual content (and thus accepting that rests of the black frame are kept if that area is not perfectly rectangular).

Could somebody explain how to do this, preferably using command line tools?


@meuh Regarding your first comment: Yes, I've tried imagemagick's deskew, but the way I have expressed that in my question was a bit ambiguous. Anyway, the deskew algorithms seem to try to make text lines horizontal. That's not what I'd like to achieve. Instead, I want the left edge of the white area to be vertical, and would like to rotate the text in this area in the same way as the area itself, even if the text was horizontal before and is not horizontal afterwards.

@meuh Regarding your second comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I'll surely try that suggestion, although it seems that in the meantime I've found a near perfect solution based on your ideas; see my own answer.

@meuh Thanks again for your second comment. In the meantime, I have tried it with a few of my images, and it worked like a charm. It produces practically the same near-perfect results as the method described in my own answer, but it is a lot faster. In summary, I've learned a bunch of very interesting things since I posted the question, but I guess I'll simply use your solution from your second comment in "production". I wouldn't have come to the idea that imagemagick can solve that problem out-of-the-box. May I suggest that you make your comment an additional answer?

This answer tries to be fast by using a feature of -trim whereby it leaves the offset of the new image within the old canvas inside the new image's information. First we do a global trim to get an image where: the topmost corner of the wanted white space should abut the top of the image, and the leftmost corner of the wanted white space should abut the left of the image. This is the dotted yellow rectangle in the image below.
We repage this image to make the canvas the same size as the new image.
A thin horizontal slice of the top is taken (of height $stripwidth in the
script below) into file line1.png, which is the red rectangle. This is trimmed (into file out4.png), as shown by theh blue rectangle. The arrowed offset %X of the result image should be where the topmost corner was found. To get a better estimate, half the width of the trimmed image (%w/2) is added to this (exagerated in the image below).
Similarly, a thin vertical slice is taken, and trimmed. The offset %Y is where the leftmost corner was found, with half the height %h/2 added.
For example, if the trimmed result of the red strip line1.png is blue out4.png, thenidentify out4.png might output
out4.png PNG 14x2 387x432+36+0 ...

which says the image is 14x2 pixels, from a canvas (line1.png) size of
387x432, at an offset of 36 pixels in x, and 0 in y.

We now have the lengths of the opposite and adjacent sides of the top left triangle. If we calculate the degrees using arctan, this is the rotation needed to make this triangle disappear, and so align the top corner with the left edge.
file=in.png
# fuzz='-fuzz 15%'
stripwidth=2
convert "$file" $fuzz -trim out.png
minwidth=$(identify -format '%w' out.png)

convert out.png +repage -crop ${minwidth}x${stripwidth}+0+0 line1.png
convert line1.png $fuzz -trim out4.png
opp=$(identify -format '0 %X +%w/2' out4.png)

ht=$(identify -format '%h' out.png)
convert out.png +repage -crop ${stripwidth}x${ht}+0+0 line2.png
convert line2.png $fuzz -trim out5.png
adj=$(identify -format '0 %Y +%h/2' out5.png)

minrot=$(echo "scale=2; pi=4*a(1); 
    opp=$opp; adj=$adj; 
    a(opp/adj)*180/pi" |
    bc -l)

convert out.png -background black -rotate -"$minrot" out2.png
convert out2.png $fuzz -trim result.png
display result.png

Note that a() is arctan (in radians) in bc. The identify -format uses %w %h %X %Y to get the width, height, x-offset, y-offset of the trimmed image in the original canvas. The extra 0 is because imagemagick adds a leading + sign, and bc does not handle that.
The result was 5.76 degrees as seen in this sh -x output:
+ convert out.png +repage -crop 387x2+0+0 line1.png
+ convert line1.png -trim out4.png
++ identify -format '0 %X +%w/2' out4.png
+ opp='0 +36 +15/2'
++ identify -format %h out.png
+ ht=432
+ convert out.png +repage -crop 2x432+0+0 line2.png
+ convert line2.png -trim out5.png
++ identify -format '0 %Y +%h/2' out5.png
+ adj='0 +381 +19/2'
++ echo 'scale=2; pi=4*a(1); 
        opp=0 +36 +15/2; adj=0 +381 +19/2; 
        a(opp/adj)*180/pi'
++ bc -l
+ minrot=5.76
+ convert out.png -background black -rotate -5.76 out2.png
+ convert out2.png -trim result.png


At first, thank you very much, and +1! This solution seems ingenious to me. I am yet far from understanding how it works and will try to learn it during the next few days. Then hopefully I'll be able to solve a small problem: The line convert line2.png $fuzz -trim out5.png produces the warning convert: geometry does not contain image 'line2.png' @ warning/attribute.c/GetImageBoundingBox/540.; this obviously keeps the script from producing the intended result. I'll try to understand the script, fix the problem and show the fix in an additional comment.

This is the sort of problem we can expect when using real-world data instead of simple examples, I suppose. Perhaps the trim removes everything? Try using fuzz='-fuzz 15%' at the start, which I needed when I tried on an image that I added some noise to.  Also, try making a wider strip; currently I use 2 pixels, so try 4 or even 10: change the '2x...' and '...x2'. I'll edit the script to use a variable $stripwidth.

The first problem is solved: I noticed that the left side of the black frame had not been trimmed in the first step, and increased the fuzz parameter to 40%. Now the image gets trimmed correctly, and this made the warning that I have cited above go away, and the further steps halfway worked. The remaining problem is that the white part now gets rotated in the right direction, but significantly too much. Of course, that's probably due to the difference between my example and the real images. I'll try to understand your code and try to fix that problem.

The step creating the horizontal blue box should try to make the result as narrow as possible, as this means the top corner has been more accurately found. Perhaps use a small loop trying a different fuzz of 10%, 20%, 30% and so on until the first one works without an error. Also, though I used %w/2 to compensate for the corner not being at the very left edge of the blue box, this is a very poor estimate. If the blue box is very wide, and the white box angle is almost horizontal, the corner is probably more like %w/6, say. The same applies to the vertical box and its height, of course.

For your simple and clean example, you can do the following; use imagemagick trim to remove most of the outer border, then try rotating by 1 degree (adding a matching black background to the newly added pixels of the now larger image), trimming again, and seeing if the size of the image was reduced. Take the best reduced size.
file=in.png
convert "$file" -trim out.png
minwidth=$(identify -format '%w' out.png)
minrot=0
for rot in $(seq 1 30)
do      convert out.png -background black -rotate -"$rot" out2.png
        convert out2.png -trim out3.png
        width=$(identify -format '%w' out3.png)
        echo "$rot degrees, width $width"
        if [ $width -lt $minwidth ]
        then    minwidth=$width minrot=$rot
        else    break
        fi
done
echo "choose rotate $minrot for min width $minwidth"
convert out.png -background black -rotate -"$minrot" out2.png
convert out2.png -trim result.png
display result.png

For the test image I got:
1 degrees, width 381
2 degrees, width 375
3 degrees, width 369
4 degrees, width 363
5 degrees, width 355
6 degrees, width 359
choose 5 width=355


If the actual frame is a little less monochrome than the example, you can try prefixing the -trim option with, say, -fuzz 15% to get a more approximate pixel colour comparison.

that certainly is an example, but it's probably the slowest method you could come up with :) I still like it!

That's a really nice idea. I don't mind speed in this case because I can let it run during the night. I'll wait a little bit longer before I mark the answer, but in every case +1!

The following solution is based on @meuh's ideas. Please upvote his answers if you find my solution useful. First I'll post my code, and then I'll explain what I have changed, mentioning only the non-obvious things.
The code is based on some assumptions that are safe for the images I have to process:

The left edge of the white area in the original images is not rotated by more than 5 degrees against a vertical line.
The white area in the original images is at least 2000 pixels high and 1000 pixels wide.

#!/usr/bin/bash

file=ScanImage7123.tif
stripwidth=4

convert "$file" -fuzz 20% -trim out.png
width=$(identify -format '%w' out.png)
height=$(identify -format '%h' out.png)

(( wd = (width / 2) ))
(( l1yoff = (height / 10) ))
(( l2yoff = (height - l1yoff) ))

convert out.png +repage -crop ${wd}x${stripwidth}+0+${l1yoff} line1.png
IFS=" x+" read a b x1 d < <(convert -fuzz 50% line1.png -format "%@" info:)

convert out.png +repage -crop ${wd}x${stripwidth}+0+${l2yoff} line2.png
IFS=" x+" read a b x2 d < <(convert -fuzz 50% line2.png -format "%@" info:)

(( a = (x1 - x2) ))
(( b = (l2yoff - l1yoff) ))
rad2deg="57.2957795130823208768"

angle=$(perl -E "say atan2(${a}, ${b}) * ${rad2deg}")

convert out.png -background black -rotate -${angle} out2.png
convert out2.png -fuzz 20% -trim result.png

The idea here is that we actually don't need to find the corners of the white area. This is important, because reliably finding the corners was impossible for me, even when playing around with different values for stripwidth. The inability to precisely determine the corners caused the white area in the resulting image to be rotated too much or too less.
My real-world images are coming from a scanner, meaning that the edges of the white area are not very sharp. This makes it quite difficult to find the corners. For example, we normally could find the top corner the following way: After the first convert operation (trim), go to the first line of pixels (at the top), walk along it from the left to the right, and stop at the first white pixel; then you have found the corner.
This is practically impossible if the top edge of the white area already is horizontal, or nearly horizontal, and gets the more difficult the less "sharp" the top edge is.
Therefore I have moved the area (the "line") that gets cropped by the second convert operation away from the top edge by one tenth of the image height. This ensures that this line intersects with the (near-) vertical border of the white area (instead of the near-horizontal border) and that we have a clear and relatively sharp horizontal transition from black to white in this line (filename line1.png).
I wanted to avoid having two horizontal transitions in line 1 (e.g. black -> white at the left side and white -> black at the right side). That's simply because I have no clue about imagemagick and no clue about what would happen in the next step if there was more than one transition in the line. Therefore, when cropping out the line, I use only half the image width. This at least makes sure that the line does not contain the sharp transition from white to black at the right side of the white area.
[ Side note: There still could be multiple transitions in the line, depending on the white area's contents (e.g., black text), but this did not impose problems in my first tests. ]
The third convert operation outputs something like 0x10+45+0. The part 0x10 denotes the dimensions of the aforementioned transition, +45 is the X coordinate where the transition begins. This is the value we are after; the read construct saves it in x1.
The same method is applied for the second "line" (filename line2.png), which is cropped out one tenth of the image height away from the image bottom (fourth convert operation). In the next line (fifth convert operation), the X coordinate of the black-to-white-transition in line 2 is saved in x2.
Now we can calculate the horizontal and the vertical distance between the transitions in line 1 and line 2, and from these distances can calculate the rotation angle.
I've used Perl to execute that calculation because bc does not provide the atan2() function, which I prefer over atan() in such cases for its ability to handle situations where the horizontal or vertical distance (or even both) is 0. I am aware that only the X difference can become 0 (unless we have an image that's only a few pixels high), and that this would not be problematic even when using the traditional atan() function. But hey, why not use the better alternative nevertheless :-)
The rest should be self-explaining.
EDIT:
The above method works very well for images in portrait format. For images in landscape format, I have noticed that I would like the top edge of the white area to be horizontal (instead of the left edge to be vertical). It shouldn't be too hard to implement that, using a similar method.

Imagemagick really is magic in what it can do, as the following shows.
You can find the bounding box of the white area by referencing the property
minimum-bounding-box of the image. With the given example, we can print the x,y co-ordinates of the vertices of the bounding box:
$ file=in.png fuzz=
$ magick $file $fuzz -format "%[minimum-bounding-box]\n" info:
  449,63 413,463 62,431 98,31

But it is much clearer if we save these co-ordinates in a variable MBR and then draw that box in red:
$ magick $file $fuzz -background black \
 -set MBR "%[minimum-bounding-box]" \
 -fill none -stroke red -strokewidth 4 -draw "polygon %[MBR]" out.png
$ display out.png

If the image is not as clean as the example, try setting fuzz='-fuzz 10%' or higher values until it works.

More magic comes with the property minimum-bounding-box:unrotate. This is the angle to rotate the bounding box rectangle to get it square in the image. We use it as follows:
magick $file $fuzz \
 -set option:angle "%[minimum-bounding-box:unrotate]" \
 -background black -rotate "%[angle]" out.png


To that we add a -trim to keep just the wanted white rectangle:
magick $file $fuzz \
 -set option:angle "%[minimum-bounding-box:unrotate]" \
 -background black -rotate "%[angle]" -trim out.png

See Unrotate an Image.

Thanks for making your comment an answer and for further explaining it. It turned out that this is the fastest method and produces the same near-perfect results as the method which is described in my own answer.
